# Get user custom meta data value and update it in WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

In woocommerce, I'm trying to add additional code to a existing php code, that stores an value to an advanced customer field in the db.

As you can see I calculate the value "Kontostandeintrag" as a result of an addition of different values and store this value in the post_meta in the Field "Kontostandeintrag". I do this for each order line.

This works fine.

As next step I would like to read the existing customer field "_kontostandaktuell" (for the customer of the order line)in the user_meta, add the actual value "Kontostandeintrag" to this field and update the field "_kontostandaktuell" again with the sum value of this fields. So after run through all order lines, I should have the sum value of all "Kontostandeintrag" values in the user_meta field "_kontostandaktuell" for each customer.

Get user custom meta data value and update it in WooCommerce

The existing code which I like to extend is:

```
add_filter('woe_get_order_value_Kontostandeintrag', function( $value, $order, $fieldname ) {

    $id = $order->get_id();
    $value =get_post_meta($id,"GS-Bargeldeinzahlung",true) +  $order->get_total() + get_post_meta($id,"GS-Mitgliedsbeitrag",true) + get_post_meta($id,"GS-Nachlass",true) + get_post_meta($id,"GS-Guthabenkonto",true);

    global $wpdb;
    $data = array("meta_value" =>$value);
    $where = array("post_id"=>$id,"meta_key" =>"Kontostandeintrag");
    $wpdb->update( "wp_postmeta", $data, $where );

    return $value;

},10,3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3, your code is a bit outdated and you don't need to use any SQL query. So I have revisited your code a bit, using [some `WC_Data` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#methods) on the available `WC_Order` Object.

Now additionally, in this function, we get the meta value from user meta key "_kontostandaktuell" and then update that meta value, adding to it, your calculated value.

The code:

```
add_filter('woe_get_order_value_Kontostandeintrag', 'filter_get_order_value_kontostandeintrag', 10, 3 );
function filter_get_order_value_kontostandeintrag( $value, $order, $fieldname ) {
    // Calculation from different order meta values
    $value  = $order->get_total() +
              $order->get_meta('GS-Bargeldeinzahlung') +
              $order->get_meta('GS-Mitgliedsbeitrag') +
              $order->get_meta('GS-Nachlass') +
              $order->get_meta('GS-Guthabenkonto');

    // Update order meta value for "Kontostandeintrag" key
    $order->update_meta_data('Kontostandeintrag', $value );
    $order->save(); // Save to database

    // Get the User ID from order
    $user_id = $order->get_customer_id();

    // Get user meta value for "_kontostandaktuell" key
    $kontostandaktuell = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_kontostandaktuell', true );

    // Update user meta value for "_kontostandaktuell" key
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_kontostandaktuell', $kontostandaktuell + $value );

    return $value;
}
```

It should work.

Related WordPress user functions documentation: [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) and [`update_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)

---

**Addition** *(related to your comment)*:

To reset `_kontostandaktuell` user field before, you should just removefrom the code:

```
// Get user meta value for "_kontostandaktuell" key
$kontostandaktuell = get_user_meta( $user_id, '_kontostandaktuell', true );
```

And remove from `update_user_meta()` function `$kontostandaktuell +`, so you will have instead:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, '_kontostandaktuell', $value );
```

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec, yes this works but I ave another problem. I need to change the values in the column _kontostandaktuell to 0 before the code is working. So I have the problem that the value grows with each code action.
Is there a possibility to expand the code with a function which  set all _kontostandaktuell to 0 before the add_fllter code start? The code is starting via cron job and without reset to zero the values are wrong. Siegfried

Comment: @uebes I have added an addition to my answer…

Comment: sorry I was to fast.

Comment: Sorry to fast. I need the the total sum '$kontostandaktuell + $value'  in the field "_kontostandaktuell" for each user.
My existing solution (code- action started by a button): 

` add_action( 'wp_ajax_db_retour', function ( $update_user_meta ) {
 $all_user_ids = get_users( 'fields=ID' );
 foreach ( $all_user_ids as $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_kontostandaktuell', 0 );
 }
 echo "Daten gelöscht, bitte TAB mit x schließen";
    });`

But better would be the first solution which includes the delete action code.
At the moment I need two buttons for the whole action.

Comment: @ LoicTheAztec ok thank you. Sorry but I am a newbie at stackOverFlow.
Thank you for your explanation. I will start a new question.